# Using json as a source for cxf-wadl2java

Tags: json, rest, cxf, auto-generate, wadl

I received a specification of a RESTful service in json format and need to create a java api library for the client.

Now swagger can do it without a problem, but I would prefer to use *cxf-wadl2java* maven plugin. By default it doesn't expect the json format. See the exception cause stack trace below.

Is there a way to configure the *cxf-wadl2java* plugin to read  json document?

> Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
>    at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
>       at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:653)
>       at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2133)
>       at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1181)
>       at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1367)
>       at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1261)
>       at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:1189)
>       at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:1178)
>       at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:1168)
>       at org.apache.cxf.tools.wadlto.jaxrs.SourceGenerator.readXmlDocument(SourceGenerator.java:1757)
>       ... 32 more

Comment: In short no......

Comment: @KarthikPrasad pessimistic but probably right. If you provided that as an answer I'd have accepted it. Do you know of a conversion tool that can do the work (and can be integrated into a maven script)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can have two step conversion. swagger.json to wadl file and then use wadl2java plugin.

1. Install npm in you machine
2. Use maven exec plugin and run command defined in [this npm package](https://github.com/LucyBot-Inc/api-spec-converter) to convert from swagger to wadl.
3. Use cxf wadl2java plugin to generate java file from generated wadl file from above.

---

***EDIT***

There is a maven plugin provided by swagger.io. Please refer a usage example [here](https://github.com/kprasad99/cxf-swagger-example)

Comment: Quite complicated but seems like the only possible solution. I'm accepting and will try that later. Thanks